# Chain rule of probability

Tags: probability

I am just working through a [tutorial](https://github.com/zjost/bayesian-linear-regression/blob/master/src/bayes-regression.ipynb) on Bayesian linear regression. In the section `Strategy` this expression comes up:

$\int p(t, \vec{w} \vert \vec{x}, D) d \vec{w}$.

They state that after applying the product rule this term can be rewritten like so:

$\int p(t \vert \vec{x}, \vec{w}) p(\vec{w} \vert D) d \vec{w}$

However, I am not sure how to get there. I was trying to use some definitions of conditional probability:

$p(x, y \vert z) = p(x \vert y, z)p(y \vert z)$

I feel like I am missing some important step. Can anybondy help me on this?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, we shall have $p(t,\vec w\mid \vec x, D) = p(t\mid \vec w,\vec x, D)p(\vec w\mid \vec x, D)$ by the chain rule.

The steps missing are that

- the inputs and parameters ($\vec x,\vec w$) should be conditionally independent given the old data $D$. $$\begin{split}p(\vec w,\vec x\mid D)&=p(\vec w\mid D)~p(\vec x\mid D)\\p(\vec w\mid \vec x, D) &= p(\vec w\mid D)\end{split}$$
- the target and old data ($t, D$) should be conditionally independent given the inputs and parameters ($\vec x,\vec w$) . $$p(t\mid \vec w,\vec x, D)=p(t\mid \vec w,\vec x)$$

These should be estabilished in the discussion on the model. They... seem to have glossed over doing so.